# "Could Not Sign In" on Apple TV

Tags: appletv

I am going nuts trying to figure out how to fix this.  When I use my Apple TV for Netflix, Youtube, NHL, etc it all works just fine.  When I try to rent a movie from Apple (iTunes) it has a black screen, the message "Could Not Sign In" and an okay button and that is it.

I have full connection to my WiFi according to the my network info in the General tab.  The only answers I have found is to use a micro-HDMI cable but this appleTV doesn't have that.  It only has an Ethernet, Optical, and HDMI ports. I have not tried to hard wire it as the TV is on the other side of the house from the router and that is how I want to use it.

Anyone have any ideas before I try to use this as a skipping stone across my pond?

Comment: Did you try to reset it and re-enter apple log in.

Comment: Yes, multiple times

Comment: did it ever work before? did you try to sign in from computer and stay signed in?

Comment: No, I haven't tried it before.  I was content with Netflix but decided to rent a movie from Apple and it didn't work.  I don't understand what you mean about signing in from my computer.  Sorry, I know TVs and Amps, not networking

Comment: I mean did you try to log in to itunes from your computer and does that works?

Comment: before you go and watch that movie lets finish this, make it a answer and you can check it off as done

Comment: I'm having the same problem. It is impossible to log in when 2FA is turned on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your Computer and log in in to iTunes with it.

Then just leave it logged in.

Now try again with your Apple TV.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it wasn't solved by resetting or restoring Apple TV from the box or via iTunes (after attaching the TV box to my computer). Turning box and/router on and off didn't work either. But I did solve the problem in the end. Download the Apple TV remote app from the App Store; follow the instructions in the app to connect your phone to your Apple TV as a remote; then sign in to iTunes via the phone app instead of the original remote (much easier anyway as you can type your Apple ID and password) and it lets you in. At least it did me. Phew, I can now access all my purchased content again. NB the app remote isn't the most intuitive thing - to move right, left, up, down just swipe on the blank bit of the screen above the menu button. Hope that helps folks.

Answer (score 0):

A "factory reset" worked for me - plugging it in via USB (and power) to a Mac running iTunes and resetting it did the trick:

http://www.howtogeek.com/214243/how-to-factory-reset-or-reboot-an-apple-tv/

Apple's instructions: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202118

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me. Yesterday iTunes was working fine. Today iTunes suddenly asking me for my password and won't accept it on either my Apple TV or computer.

I kept getting a 2-factor authentication popup on my iphone saying a device is trying to connect. Upon selecting OK, instruction is to enter a 6-digit verification code in the password field. There was no request from iTunes for the 6-digit code, simply the message "Could not sign in".

I turned off 2-factor authentication in iCloud. Tried signing back into iTunes and Hey Presto, I'm able to reconnect to iTunes.

Comment: Turning off a security feature isn't a great solution.  At best, it's a troubleshooting step on your way to the solution.  I, and Apple, recommend that you immediately turn 2FA back on and continue with your troubleshooting to find the real cause of the problem.  Don't leave your account with 2FA turned off.

Answer (score 0):

My apple TV is on a hard-wired ethernet connection. After I changed my AppleID, I struggled and struggled to sign in to the iTunes store on my apple TV.  What finally worked for me was downloading the Apple TV remote app, and then discovering that I couldn't "see" my appleTV because it wasn't on the same wireless connection.  Long story short, I unplugged the ethernet cable from the apple TV (making it wireless), and tried again, using the iPhone apple TV remote, which worked great, and I was able to sign in.  Hallelujah!  I plugged the ethernet cable back in, and I am in business.

Answer (score 0):

#### I have an apple tv v3, and same issue. I managed to fix it by doing a factory reset.

- Insert a micro usb cable into your apple tv, and the power cord.
- Unhook the hdmi
- Connect the USB to your computer
- Open iTunes
- iTunes should give you an option to reset the device to factory settings.

Once done, you can set it up again!

[Snagged from here](https://www.idownloadblog.com/2016/03/01/how-to-apple-tv-recovery-mode/)